# Selecting one to many which one is better

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nhibernate, one-to-many

In a one to many relationship situation which of the following has better performance.

1st approach

```
public Order GetOrder(long orderId) {
    var orderDetails = 
        (from o in Orders
        from d in OrderDetails
        where d.OrderId = o.Id && o.Id = orderId
        select new {
            Order = o,
            Detail = d
        }).ToList();

    var order = orderDetails.First().Order;
    order.Details = orderDetails.Select(od => od.Detail).ToList();

    return order;
}
```

2nd approach

```
public Order GetOrder(long orderId) {
    var order = Orders.First(o => o.Id == orderId);
    order.Details = OrderDetails.Where(od => od.OrderId = orderId).ToList();

    return order;
}
```

The point I am trying to figure out (in terms of performance) is, in first approach there is single query but repeated data is being selected where, in second approach, there are two seperate queries but selecting only the data that is enough.

You can assume `Orders` and `OrderDetails` are `IQueryable<T>` of EntityFramework (`dbContext.Set<T>()`) or NHibernate (`session.Query<T>()`). I tried with both and they create very similar sql queries. Also as far as I know, these ORM's built in one to many queries use something like the first approach.

UPDATE, to clarify what I am asking: Which one (single query but repeated data or only required data but multiple queries) performs better under which circumstances? There may be many situations that I may not think of. That's why I am not trying  benchmarking. As already stated in some answers column count or more joins were the kinds of answers that I expected. (There may be also something about row count of table and/or result set). Based on these kind of answers I may try benchmarking. And of course I am asking why? I am not trying to solve Order - OrderDetail problem or solve anything at all. I am trying to learn and understand when to use single query but repeated data or only required data but multiple queries.

Comment: As usual, questions about which alternative performs better can only be answered by the the one who asks. Sometimes one query is faster, sometimes two. We can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

A single one-to-many query is pretty straightforward for ORMs. It's when you need to make several interrelated one-to-many queries that performance considerations start making themselves known.

Answer (score 1):

always measure performance for your particular case. if order table has few-small sized columns, getting all data in one round trip may be better. if order tables has too many or blob columns, issuing 2 seperate queries may outperform.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `EntityFramework`, you should either call `Include` on the `context`

```
var order = context.Orders.Include(x => x.Details).First(x => x.Id == orderId);
```

[Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I already know about built in one-to-many support and navigation properties etc. For now I am just interested in comparison of these two approachs in terms of performance.

Comment: @MehmetAtaş - Have you tried benchmarking both approaches?